# remote datasource in jquery autocomplete

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I have to show searched text in the jquery autocomplete list. I have function which is adding the search text in the list but I have to do it with remote datasource. I have a URL which is returning `array`.

working demo with static array list  [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kLx7uy7b/2/)

I have to add the same functionality with remote data source. How can I add search text in response.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

   var tagsElem = $("#tags");

   tagsElem.autocomplete({
        source : "search.php",
        search : function( event, ui ){
            if(check(response,tagsElem.val()))
              response[response.length]=tagsElem.val()              
            tagsElem.autocomplete( "option", "source", response);
        },
        open: function( event, ui ) {
            if(check(response,tagsElem.val())){
            tagsElem.next().find('li:last a').append(' <span style="color:red;">new</span>');
            }
                   }
    });

    function check(arrayTag,value){
     for(i=0;i<len;i++){
        if( arrayTag[i]==value)
                return false
        }
        return true
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I can see you are using Jquery UI.

I assume you know [how to change to remote source](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote) and that returns a simple array answer.

As Jquery UI works, it then changes your simple json array to:

```
[{label:<array_value1>,value:<array_value1>},{label:<array_value2>,value:<array_value2>}]
```

To accomplish what you want, you have to then in response event do:

```
            response: function(index,obj){
                var v = tagsElem.val();
                var add = {};
                add['label'] = v;
                add['value'] = v;
                obj.content[obj.content.length] = add;
            }
```

The 'obj.content' is the above json array.

That will add search key to the response array.

Please note that 'tagsElem' in above example refers to tagsElem in your JSFiddle.

Here is example that I got working, not in fiddle but on localhost:
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rohh7chL/)